# Включить/просмотреть журнал ошибок в Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ubuntu

До обновления до Ubuntu 12.10 в предыдущей версии отключил то ли оповещение об ошибках, то ли ведение журнала ошибок. Теперь нужно чтобы я мог снова просматривать все сообщения об ошибках в системе. Помню только что отключал изменяя конфиг вручную.

Comment: Имя файла лога которого хотите смотреть. Это я как бы спрашиваю что именно вы хотите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Файлы логов находятся по-умолчанию в /var/log.Чтобы узнать, какие файлы протоколов у вас являются основными, откройте файл конфигурации syslogd —/etc/syslog.conf. Прочитав его, вы узнаете, какие файлы протоколирования есть в вашей системе и для чего они используются.P.S. Разработчик не рекомендует обновление системы, предпочтителен вариант "чистой" установки!

Comment: Вообще там по дефолту rsyslog.